# Enemies' and bullets' positions' value does not change - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a pygame shooting game where you have to use space station to shoot enemies flying from the top of the screen to the bottom. However, I noticed that the **Y** positions of **enemy**(`enemy.pos_y`) and **bullet**(`bullet.pos_y`) is just the position where they spawn, but this position doesn't change even though the enemy moves in the window of the game (because of the `move()` function in class `Enemy`) and also bullet moves (also because of the `move()` function but in `Bullet` class) and that's obvious because the Y values are constant (`enemy.pos_y`=-30 and `bullet.pos_y`=`STATION_HEIGHT` - 5. So is there any solution to make those positions' values change (I'm saying **value** because on screen enemies' and bullets' positions change) and still spawn them in those given positions? This issue stops my further steps, because for example making collision between enemies and bullets is impossible, because it's like they never move, and so they never meet. So how to make detect those objects' position's value's change?

In this picture you can see that enemies' positions' value remains the same: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKcrC.jpg)

**Enemies' class:**

```
    import pygame
    import math


    class Enemy:
        def __init__(
        self, pos_x: float, pos_y: float, texture: pygame.Surface, speed: float
    ):
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.texture = texture
        self.speed = speed

        def move(self):
            self.pos_y += self.speed
```

**Bullets' class:**

```
    import pygame


    class Bullet:
        def __init__(
        self, pos_x: float, pos_y: float, texture: pygame.Surface, speed: float
    ):
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.texture = texture
        self.speed = speed

        def move(self):
            self.pos_y -= self.speed
```

**Here I display enemies and bullets (in main loop):**

```
    running = True
    while running:
        all_event = pygame.event.get()
        for event in all_event:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                shot_sound.play()
            # Bullets
            bullet = Bullet(
                bulletX + station.pos_x,
                STATION_HEIGHT + 10,
                bullet_texture,
                BULLET_SPEED,
            )           

            bullets.append(bullet)
            print(f'position X={bullet.pos_x}')

     # Enemies move
        for enemy in enemies:
            for i in range(3):
                enemy.move()

        for i in range(3):
            enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(67, 520), -30, enemy_texture, ENEMY_SPEED)
            start_time+=1
            if start_time > 200:
                enemies.append(enemy)
                start_time = 0
```

The whole code you can find on my Github: [enter link description here](https://github.com/opacia/iss_escape_21)

ps. I'm sorry if this question and problem's explanation isn't well-written, but this is my first question here on stackoverflow so I'm not really experienced, I'm waiting for questions if something's not understandable.

Comment: *" I noticed that the Y positions of enemy(enemy.pos_y) and bullet(bullet.pos_y) is just the position where they spawn"* No, this is impossible. Either the objects do not move or the position is changing with the movement. Why do you think the position doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually just print the position of a newly created bullet. If you want to see the position of a moving bullet, you need to move the print statement in the loop that moves the bullets:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.move()
        print(f'enemy position Y={enemy.pos_y}')

    # [...]

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.move()
        print(f'bullet position Y={bullet.pos_y}')

    # [...]
```

or

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for i, enemy in enumerate(enemies):
        enemy.move()
        print(f'position of enemy {i} Y={enemy.pos_y}')

    # [...]

    for i, bullet in enumerate(bullets):
        bullet.move()
        print(f'position of bullet {i} Y={bullet.pos_y}')

    # [...]
```